# How to put records into a Kinesis stream from a NodeJS app (lambda)

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis

I have a lambda function that needs to put records into a Kinesis stream. I am not getting an error (that I recognize), but the messages never seem to make it to the stream...

I know the stream itself works since I can push messages to it with the aws cli app.
I have verified the stream name and other parameters passed to the putRecord() function.

I am using this code to push the records to the stream:

```
const params = {
      Data: payload,
      PartitionKey: partitionKey,
      StreamName: this.streamName,
    };
    const res = await this.awsKinesis.putRecord(params);
```

`res` is a big complicated object, but it contains `error: null`...

```
{
    "domain": null,
    "service": {
        "config": {
            "credentials": {
                "expired": false,
                "expireTime": null,
                "accessKeyId": "ASIAT5YUDX4OWH5FGFYE",
                "sessionToken": "FQoGZXIvYXdzEJr//////////wEaDFGkyxe1r9QSkkhSSyKKAgbrbB6ef77wtuCC4zIH3YB7C0xJPPoql1YtRGaxba5ZDSCwBBRSQ0cBeTPMmtdUqRGshdJjjLosON6QG0FGWdt3TNDrENxqFtxjrQAbCHXfIx3ARtnn6r2agZjXi9cGZhkdpvUMSIUpaC3ZC+E9wLLvkZyQBfTSsv6QdcoaKGqT8tJ9Px7Wp5BSV3Nw//NE0GtJwv0pXiQrb3c6p6GkETtAxBBVVgwJP1WYdF+kh+Gg24DxMPwwy66ayD6E7oZIWB4i7JaqMXHoDjf9D51bpWPUAVCKF9AVn3t4JiKFBVw7lFQC0m91N9HdcKLzGmjpvX4JJNzKwBA/D1TfALDsprrvU1u7r/RlyabzKIHtpeIF",
                "envPrefix": "AWS"
            },
            "credentialProvider": {
                "providers": [null, null, null, null]
            },
            "region": "eu-west-1",
            "logger": null,
            "apiVersions": {},
            "apiVersion": null,
            "endpoint": "kinesis.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
            "httpOptions": {
                "timeout": 120000
            },
            "maxRedirects": 10,
            "paramValidation": true,
            "sslEnabled": true,
            "s3ForcePathStyle": false,
            "s3BucketEndpoint": false,
            "s3DisableBodySigning": true,
            "computeChecksums": true,
            "convertResponseTypes": true,
            "correctClockSkew": false,
            "customUserAgent": null,
            "dynamoDbCrc32": true,
            "systemClockOffset": 0,
            "signatureVersion": "v4",
            "signatureCache": true,
            "retryDelayOptions": {},
            "useAccelerateEndpoint": false
        },
        "isGlobalEndpoint": false,
        "endpoint": {
            "protocol": "https:",
            "host": "kinesis.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
            "port": 443,
            "hostname": "kinesis.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
            "pathname": "/",
            "path": "/",
            "href": "https://kinesis.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/"
        },
        "_clientId": 1
    },
    "operation": "putRecord",
    "params": {
        "Data": "<< THE MESSAGE >>",
        "PartitionKey": "c770e429-52e7-47c4-bcbc-497548ff9dee",
        "StreamName": "my-stream"
    },
    "httpRequest": {
        "method": "POST",
        "path": "/",
        "headers": {
            "User-Agent": "aws-sdk-nodejs/2.290.0 linux/v6.10.3 exec-env/AWS_Lambda_nodejs6.10"
        },
        "body": "",
        "endpoint": {
            "protocol": "https:",
            "host": "kinesis.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
            "port": 443,
            "hostname": "kinesis.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
            "pathname": "/",
            "path": "/",
            "href": "https://kinesis.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/"
        },
        "region": "eu-west-1",
        "_userAgent": "aws-sdk-nodejs/2.290.0 linux/v6.10.3 exec-env/AWS_Lambda_nodejs6.10"
    },
    "startTime": "2019-01-24T08:25:42.574Z",
    "response": {
        "request": "~context",
        "data": null,
        "error": null,
        "retryCount": 0,
        "redirectCount": 0,
        "httpResponse": {
            "headers": {},
            "streaming": false,
            "stream": null
        },
        "maxRetries": 3,
        "maxRedirects": 10
    },
    "_asm": {
        "currentState": "validate",
        "states": {
            "validate": {
                "accept": "build",
                "fail": "error"
            },
            "build": {
                "accept": "afterBuild",
                "fail": "restart"
            },
            "afterBuild": {
                "accept": "sign",
                "fail": "restart"
            },
            "sign": {
                "accept": "send",
                "fail": "retry"
            },
            "retry": {
                "accept": "afterRetry",
                "fail": "afterRetry"
            },
            "afterRetry": {
                "accept": "sign",
                "fail": "error"
            },
            "send": {
                "accept": "validateResponse",
                "fail": "retry"
            },
            "validateResponse": {
                "accept": "extractData",
                "fail": "extractError"
            },
            "extractError": {
                "accept": "extractData",
                "fail": "retry"
            },
            "extractData": {
                "accept": "success",
                "fail": "retry"
            },
            "restart": {
                "accept": "build",
                "fail": "error"
            },
            "success": {
                "accept": "complete",
                "fail": "complete"
            },
            "error": {
                "accept": "complete",
                "fail": "complete"
            },
            "complete": {
                "accept": null,
                "fail": null
            }
        }
    },
    "_haltHandlersOnError": false,
    "_events": {
        "validate": [null, null, null, null],
        "afterBuild": [null, null, null],
        "restart": [null],
        "sign": [null],
        "validateResponse": [null],
        "send": [null],
        "httpHeaders": [null],
        "httpData": [null],
        "httpDone": [null],
        "retry": [null, null, null, null, null, null],
        "afterRetry": [null],
        "build": [null],
        "extractData": [null, null],
        "extractError": [null, null],
        "httpError": [null]
    }
}
```

I would expect a message to appear in the Kinesis stream and to fire the lambda that is triggered by the stream, but this never happens. 
Even in the web console, the Kinesis stream does not show any activity on the monitoring tab.
What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Kinesis.html#putRecord-property) the return value is a `Request` object.

> putRecord(params = {}, callback) ⇒ AWS.Request

You need to call `promise()` on this `Request` object in order to get a promise that you can then `await` on.

```
const res = await this.awsKinesis.putRecord(params).promise();
```